# Calcular media de resultados de un JSON obtenido de una consulta PHP

Tags: javascript

Completando una pregunta anterior (creo que solucionada), quiero calcular la media de un valor comprendido entre dos fechas. Obtengo un JSON a partir de una consulta PHP a la que le envío tres parámetros, un número identificador, y las dos fechas. Si envío una fecha concreta ejemplo 2022-09-24 ya muestro el valor, pero si es un intervalo (2022-09-24 - 2022-09-26) debería de calcular la media.
La estructura del JSON:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 238,
      "cad": "1",
      "time": "2022-09-24",
      "val": "0.0000",
      "mag": 3
    },
    {
      "id": 238,
      "cad": "1",
      "time": "2022-09-24",
      "val": "0.0477",
      "mag": 4
    },
    {
      "id": 238,
      "cad": "1",
      "time": "2022-09-24",
      "val": "1.0000",
      "mag": 5
    },
    {
      "id": 238,
      "cad": "1",
      "time": "2022-09-24",
      "val": "0.1514",
      "mag": 6
    },
     {
      "id": 238,
      "cad": "1",
      "time": "2022-09-25",
      "val": "1.0000",
      "mag": 5
    },
    {
      "id": 238,
      "cad": "1",
      "time": "2022-09-25",
      "val": "0.1623",
      "mag": 6
    },
    {
      "id": 238,
      "cad": "1",
      "time": "2022-09-26",
      "val": "1.0000",
      "mag": 5
    },
    {
      "id": 238,
      "cad": "1",
      "time": "2022-09-26",
      "val": "0.1838",
      "mag": 6
    }
  ]
}
```

Tengo que calcular la media para los que tiene la mag con el valor 6 por ejemplo. La función por la que obtengo los resultados:

```
function dise(){
    var elemento = document.getElementById("formulario");
    obje = document.getElementById('par');
    obje1 = document.getElementById('date1');
    obje2 = document.getElementById('date2');
    var txt='';
    txt = "\""+obje.value+"\"";
    txt1= "'"+obje1.value+"'";
    txt2= "'"+obje2.value+"'";
    url_obje = 'par='+txt+'&date1='+txt1+'&date2='+txt2;
    par(obje.value, obje1.value, obje2.value);
}
//var xmlhttp; 
function par(parcelId, date1Id, date2Id){ 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
    else
        {// code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    var url = "obDise.php";
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var params = {
                par: parId,
                date1: date1Id,
                date2: date2Id
            }
    xhr.open('POST', url);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    var onError = function() {
        alert('error');
    }
    xhr.onerror = onError;
    xhr.onload = function(){
        xhr.responseText;
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
        if(xhr.status === 200){
            var datos = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
           //inicializo una variable contador, tendrá más valores
            let contador = {'6':0};
           //inicializo variable suma, tendrá más valores   
            let suma = {'6':0};
           //inicializo variable promedio, tendrá más valores
            let promedio = {'6':0};
            for(var i in datos.data){
                if(datos.data[i].mag === 6){
                    suma['6'] += parseFloat(datos.data[i].value);
                    contador['6']++;
                }               
            }
           promedio['6'] = parseFloat(suma['6']/contador['6'].toFixed(4);
        }
    }
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify(params));
}
```

Comment: ¿porque usas `value` o `magnitude` cuando en el json es `val` o `mag`?

Comment: había construido a mano la estructura del json :-(

Comment: bueno, ahora ya te deberia funcionar (aunque en [mis pruebas](https://jsfiddle.net/zxnwv042/) no hace falta el JSON.parse()) para realizar los cálculos que desees en javascript, no?

Comment: si @masterguru el resultado lo muestra, lo que quiero hacer es la media de los valores si envío más de una fecha: (valor de la fecha 1 + valor de la fecha 2 + valor de la fecha 3 ...)  / número de resultados.

Comment: Pero eso es matemática... ahora que ya sabes recorrer el json correctamente ¿no puedes aplicar tu mismo la formula metiendo el resultando en una variable que haga de sumatoria y que hayas inicializado antes del bucle?  Dicho de otro modo, al menos inténtalo y si no te sale lo agregas a la pregunta... sino parece que lo tengamos que hacer nosotros por ti y así no es como funciona este sitio... corregimos errores, pero cuando hay intentos de lo que se pretende conseguir. No solo por enunciar lo que uno quiere aquí se lo vamos a hacer.

Comment: Y no quiero ser desagradable, quiero ayudar, pero no trabajar gratis porque a ti no te apetece probarlo :-)   Quizás deberías releer lo del [ask] para entender de nuevo como deben ser las buenas preguntas.  Pensé desde el principio que el problema era que no conseguias acceder a los valores del json por eso del value y magnitude, y eso ya está superado ahora.

Comment: Puedes editar [mi ejemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/zxnwv042/) y hacer tus pruebas alli cargandote todo el contenido del bucle y probando de realizar el sumatorio que he indicado antes en una nueva variable.  Y cuando lo tengas lo puedes aplicar a tu código.

Comment: no, no, no lo malinterpretes xD, estoy viendo como hacerlo, mi duda empezó planteándome si debía de hacer la media en el php o no...

Comment: La puedes hacer en el javascript, no parece que eso vaya a ser un problema si ya tienes el json... pero si quieres hacerla en PHP supongo que seria otra llamada ajax, y desaprovecharias la que ya tienes ahora, no se, eso ya es tu decisión :-)

Comment: Prueba con `suma += parseFloat(datos.data[i].val);` o `suma += Number(datos.data[i].val);` o con `suma = suma + parseFloat(datos.data[i].val);`

Comment: el resultado por consola, es que muestra el primer val 0.1514 y le suma el segundo val >> 0.1514+0.1623= 0.3137 y después le suma el tercer val >> 0.3137 + 0.1838 = 0.4975. debería de mostrar el resultado final, no?

Comment: no se que quieres decir... si te preocupa ver esas sumas no pongas el console.log dentro del bucle, sino cuando ya has salido de el y tan solo te mostrará el resultado final de la suma, ¿no?  Es que no entiendo donde ves el problema, ahora ya suma numeros (antes concatenaba)

Comment: si @masterguru correcto culpa mía no había quitado el console.log del bucle. y para hacer la media quedaría así ? suma = suma + parseFloat(datos.data[i].val)/datos.data[i].val.length;

Comment: para la media mejor que metas otra variable inicializada tambien antes del bucle, que haga de contador en el mismo condicional (le vas sumando uno cada vez) donde haces la suma, y al final, ya fuera del bucle, la puedes calcular con algo así: `let media = suma/contador` y para verla le pones un `console.log(media)` a ver si te cuadra

Comment: he editado la pregunta original, con la posible solución, no es demasiado elegante al tener más valores, pero puede valer. gracias @masterguru por tu tiempo.

Comment: Hay dos fallos en la solución, que por cierto no debe ir en la pregunta, sino en la respuestas.  1)  De nuevo usas `value` cuando segun tu json es `val` aquí: `suma['6'] += parseFloat(datos.data[i].value);`.  y 2) No cierras bien esta línea: `promedio['6'] = parseFloat(suma['6']/contador['6'].toFixed(4);`  pues le falta un paréntesis de cierre despues de contador['6']. Debe quedar así: `promedio['6'] = parseFloat(suma['6']/contador['6']).toFixed(4);`.  Lo de ponerlo en un objeto de salida supongo que será por otros motivos que desconocemos, pero sino no hacia falta.